# Getted variable from api through controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have problem with setting and getting variable through controllers.

I create service

```
    app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var data = null;

    return {
        setProperty: function(value) {
            data = value;

        },
        getProperty: function () {

            return data;
        }
    };
});
```

And my controllers:

```
    app.controller('articleCtrl', function($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {
       $http.get('api/article')
            .then(function(result){
            articleData = result.data;
            $scope.article = articleData;

            sharedProperties.setProperty(articleData.id);

        })});

app.controller('commentsCtrl', function($http, $scope, sharedProperties) {
    id = sharedProperties.getProperty();
    $http.get('api/article/'+id+'/comments')
        .then(function(result){
        commentsList = result.data;
        $scope.comments = commentsList;

    });
```

I need "id" from article use in my commentsCtrl - its set ok, but when i call sharedProperties.get() its still return default "null".

Any ideas how to fix this? Or how to use getted id from article controller in comments controller?

Thanks a lot for your feedbacks!

Comment: Are you injecting sharedProperties?

Comment: What do u mean "injecting"

Comment: app.controller('articleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', sharedProperties, function($scope, $http, sharedProperties) { }) <- I mean that, injecting the dependencies.

Comment: When i try to use app.controller('articleCtrl', ['$scope','$http', sharedProperties, function($scope, $http, sharedProperties) { ... }]); there is an error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: sharedProperties" and whole script die.

Comment: Put the sharedProperties in single quotes maybe?

Comment: Still returning null. plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/bSCBfN3SVrjGkAhgZWLz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function () {

this.data = null;

return {
    setProperty: function(value) {
        this.data = value;

    },
    getProperty: function () {

        return this.data;
    }
};
```

});

============= EDIT =============

Ok - now that I see what you're doing, this isn't really the best way to do things. You should be referencing the id of the article by the $stateParams (or similar $params) from the URL. See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router for examples. Basically, there are a few ways to deal with this, as you currently have a race situation happening in your plunkr (ie the value isn't set prior to when your second controller needs it). In the ideal situation, you'd simply have a `$stateParams.id` value that is "1" or whatever you define in your route. Then, when you initialize your controller, you simply pass in those `$stateParams` and you have the value right there.

The second way you can do this (if you need data loaded prior to initializing the controller), is to set up a `resolve` in your route so that the api is hit prior to loading that state. In this case, you can already pass in the comments to your second controller prior to the page loading.

I hope this helps!

Comment: There is still same problem. Data is set, but getProperty return default null.

Comment: can you post a plunkr/fiddle?